# Android ListView let rows highlighted

Tags: android, listview, highlight

I have a ListView that I would like to highlight multiple rows programatically after they were loaded.

**Problem**: my code to highlight them (through setSelection()) is not making any effect.

**Question**: do you know why my rows are not getting highlighted and how to fix the code?

I set my ListView property to allow **multiple choices**:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, assetBookingsStringArray);
        assetBookingsListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        assetBookingsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Code point where I check which rows should be highlighted and **try highlight them**:

```
ArrayList<Integer> bookingConflicts = getConflicts(assetBookings);

            if (bookingConflicts.size() > 0) {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "We could not book your request because there are other conflicting bookings conflicting with yours, please choose another time period...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                for(Integer i: bookingConflicts) {

                    assetBookingsListView.setSelection(i.intValue());

                }
            }
```

Comment: Post your full adapter class

Comment: Hi @FerdousAhamed the full class is there. I don't have anything else in the code...